# How to install NS-3 simulator correctly using cygwin on windows 7

Tags: python, bash, python-2.7, cygwin, ns-3

I need to run NS-3 simulator on my windows 7 so I installed cygwin and with devel, python and utils packages. I got a problem when I run `./build.py` command as the following :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./build.py", line 10, in <module>
    from util import run_command, fatal, CommandError
  File "/home/user-PC/ns-allinone-3.25/util.py", line 3, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 430, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1266, in <module>
    import binascii as _binascii
ImportError: No such file or directory
```

Note that I changed directory to the directory that contains the file of build.py and other files of ns-3 in the directory of `{system root}/cygwin/home/user-PC`.

in my ns-3.25 folder, I have the following files:

AUTHORS , doc, Makefile, scratch, testpy.supp, VERSION, waf-tools bindings,        examples, README, src, utils, waf, wscript CHANGES.html, LICENSE, RELEASE_NOTES,    test.py, utils.py, waf.bat, wutils.py.

While in the main folder of this release of ns-3, I have the following including the folder of ns-3.25:

bake, constants.pyc, pybindgen-0.17.0.post49+ng0e4e3bc, util.pyc,
build.py, netanim-3.107, README, constants.py, ns-3.25, util.py.

I tried this command `python -v build.py |& tee build.log`  and got the following:

```
user@user-PC /home/user-PC/ns-allinone-3.25
$ python -v build.py |& tee build.log
# installing zipimport hook
import zipimport # builtin
# installed zipimport hook
# /usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/site.py
import site # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/site.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/os.py
import os # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/os.pyc
import errno # builtin
import posix # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py
import posixpath # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.py
import stat # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/stat.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.py
import genericpath # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/genericpath.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.py
import warnings # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/warnings.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.py
import linecache # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/linecache.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/types.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/types.py
import types # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/types.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.py
import UserDict # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/UserDict.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.py
import _abcoll # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/_abcoll.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/abc.py
import abc # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/abc.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.py
import _weakrefset # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/_weakrefset.pyc
import _weakref # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.py
import copy_reg # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/copy_reg.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.py
import traceback # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/traceback.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.py
import sysconfig # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sysconfig.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/re.py
import re # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/re.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py
import sre_compile # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.pyc
import _sre # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py
import sre_parse # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.py
import sre_constants # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/sre_constants.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.dll", 2);
import _locale # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_locale.dll
# /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.py
import _sysconfigdata # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/_sysconfigdata.pyc
# zipimport: found 90 names in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/paramiko-1.16.0-py2.7.egg
# zipimport: found 29 names in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/ecdsa-0.13-py2.7.egg
import encodings # directory /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings
# /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.py
import encodings # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/__init__.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.py
import codecs # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/codecs.pyc
import _codecs # builtin
# /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.py
import encodings.aliases # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/aliases.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.py
import encodings.utf_8 # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/encodings/utf_8.pyc
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jun  1 2015, 18:05:38)
[GCC 4.9.2] on cygwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
# /usr/lib/python2.7/__future__.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/__future__.py
import __future__ # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/__future__.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.py
import optparse # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/optparse.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.py
import textwrap # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/textwrap.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/string.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/string.py
import string # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/string.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.dll", 2);
import strop # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/strop.dll
# /usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.py
import gettext # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/gettext.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/locale.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/locale.py
import locale # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/locale.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.dll", 2);
import operator # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/operator.dll
# /usr/lib/python2.7/functools.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/functools.py
import functools # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/functools.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.dll", 2);
import _functools # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_functools.dll
# /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.py
import copy # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/copy.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.py
import weakref # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/weakref.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/struct.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/struct.py
import struct # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/struct.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.dll", 2);
import _struct # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_struct.dll
import xml # directory /usr/lib/python2.7/xml
# /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/__init__.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/__init__.py
import xml # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/__init__.pyc
import xml.dom # directory /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom
# /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/__init__.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/__init__.py
import xml.dom # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/__init__.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/domreg.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/domreg.py
import xml.dom.domreg # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/domreg.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minicompat.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minicompat.py
import xml.dom.minicompat # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minicompat.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.py
import xml.dom.minidom # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/minidom.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/xmlbuilder.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/xmlbuilder.py
import xml.dom.xmlbuilder # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/xmlbuilder.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/NodeFilter.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/NodeFilter.py
import xml.dom.NodeFilter # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/xml/dom/NodeFilter.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.py
import shlex # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/shlex.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/collections.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/collections.py
import collections # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/collections.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.dll", 2);
import _collections # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_collections.dll
# /usr/lib/python2.7/keyword.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/keyword.py
import keyword # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/keyword.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/heapq.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/heapq.py
import heapq # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/heapq.pyc
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.dll", 2);
import itertools # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/itertools.dll
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.dll", 2);
import _heapq # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/_heapq.dll
import thread # builtin
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.dll", 2);
import cStringIO # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/cStringIO.dll
# /home/user-PC/ns-allinone-3.25/constants.pyc matches /home/user-PC/ns-allinone-3.25/constants.py
import constants # precompiled from /home/user-PC/ns-allinone-3.25/constants.pyc
# /home/user-PC/ns-allinone-3.25/util.pyc matches /home/user-PC/ns-allinone-3.25/util.py
import util # precompiled from /home/user-PC/ns-allinone-3.25/util.pyc
# /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py
import subprocess # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.pyc
import gc # builtin
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.dll", 2);
import time # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/time.dll
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.dll", 2);
import select # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/select.dll
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.dll", 2);
import fcntl # dynamically loaded from /usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/fcntl.dll
# /usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc matches /usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py
import pickle # precompiled from /usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.pyc
import marshal # builtin
dlopen("/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.dll", 2);
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "build.py", line 10, in <module>
    from util import run_command, fatal, CommandError
  File "/home/user-PC/ns-allinone-3.25/util.py", line 3, in <module>
    import subprocess
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/subprocess.py", line 430, in <module>
    import pickle
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/pickle.py", line 1266, in <module>
    import binascii as _binascii
ImportError: No such file or directory
# clear __builtin__._
# clear sys.path
# clear sys.argv
# clear sys.ps1
# clear sys.ps2
# clear sys.exitfunc
# clear sys.exc_type
# clear sys.exc_value
# clear sys.exc_traceback
# clear sys.last_type
# clear sys.last_value
# clear sys.last_traceback
# clear sys.path_hooks
# clear sys.path_importer_cache
# clear sys.meta_path
# clear sys.flags
# clear sys.float_info
# restore sys.stdin
# restore sys.stdout
# restore sys.stderr
# cleanup __main__
# cleanup[1] cStringIO
# cleanup[1] __future__
# cleanup[1] site
# cleanup[1] sysconfig
# cleanup[1] thread
# cleanup[1] gc
# cleanup[1] select
# cleanup[1] abc
# cleanup[1] _weakrefset
# cleanup[1] gettext
# cleanup[1] sre_constants
# cleanup[1] constants
# cleanup[1] _codecs
# cleanup[1] zope
# cleanup[1] collections
# cleanup[1] _struct
# cleanup[1] _heapq
# cleanup[1] _warnings
# cleanup[1] shlex
# cleanup[1] fcntl
# cleanup[1] zipimport
# cleanup[1] _sysconfigdata
# cleanup[1] optparse
# cleanup[1] struct
# cleanup[1] textwrap
# cleanup[1] _collections
# cleanup[1] strop
# cleanup[1] _functools
# cleanup[1] keyword
# cleanup[1] signal
# cleanup[1] traceback
# cleanup[1] marshal
# cleanup[1] itertools
# cleanup[1] posix
# cleanup[1] exceptions
# cleanup[1] _weakref
# cleanup[1] heapq
# cleanup[1] locale
# cleanup[1] functools
# cleanup[1] encodings
# cleanup[1] operator
# cleanup[1] string
# cleanup[1] encodings.utf_8
# cleanup[1] codecs
# cleanup[1] encodings.aliases
# cleanup[1] re
# cleanup[1] _locale
# cleanup[1] sre_compile
# cleanup[1] _sre
# cleanup[1] sre_parse
# cleanup[2] copy_reg
# cleanup[2] xml.dom
# cleanup[2] xml.dom.NodeFilter
# cleanup[2] xml
# cleanup[2] posixpath
# cleanup[2] errno
# cleanup[2] _abcoll
# cleanup[2] xml.dom.minicompat
# cleanup[2] types
# cleanup[2] genericpath
# cleanup[2] stat
# cleanup[2] warnings
# cleanup[2] UserDict
# cleanup[2] xml.dom.domreg
# cleanup[2] copy
# cleanup[2] os.path
# cleanup[2] xml.dom.minidom
# cleanup[2] weakref
# cleanup[2] linecache
# cleanup[2] time
# cleanup[2] xml.dom.xmlbuilder
# cleanup[2] os
# cleanup sys
# cleanup __builtin__
# cleanup ints: 726 unfreed ints
# cleanup floats
```

Also I tried with bake and got the following:

```
user@user-PC /home/user-PC/ns-allinone-3.25/bake/bake
$ ./Bake.py build
./Bake.py: line 26: $' \n Bake.py\n\n This is the main Bake file, it stores all the classes related to the\n basic Bake operation. The class Bake is responsible to identify and \n execute the defined options  \n': command not found
C:/cygwin64/bin/import.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./Bake.py: line 29: try:: command not found
./Bake.py: line 30: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 31: except: command not found
./Bake.py: line 32: from: command not found
C:/cygwin64/bin/import.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
C:/cygwin64/bin/import.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
C:/cygwin64/bin/import.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
C:/cygwin64/bin/import.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
C:/cygwin64/bin/import.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
C:/cygwin64/bin/import.exe: error while loading shared libraries: ?: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
./Bake.py: line 39: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 40: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 41: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 42: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 43: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 44: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 45: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 46: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 47: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 48: from: command not found
./Bake.py: line 50: syntax error near unexpected token `('
./Bake.py: line 50: `def signal_handler(signal, frame):'
```

[Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/kl13gjz5umr4nz0/file.txt?dl=0) is the `cygcheck -c` output. 
How to get NS-3 installed successfully ?

Comment: Please no images when you can cat and paste the text of command and output. You did better than most but pasting the text is the right way. 2nd: it is better to report the link of the upstream source, almost no one knows ns-3

Comment: Any clue what `ImportError: No such file or directory` is referring ? May be the `--disable-nsc is related` ? Check if `build.py` has a more verbose mode.

Comment: @matzeri : what did you mean by "build.py has a more verbose mode"

Comment: @matzeri : I used "--disable-nsc" option but nothing changed, I've got the same error

Comment: @matzeri : you said "it is better to report the link of the upstream source", so how to perform that ?

Comment: May be as [link](https://www.nsnam.org/)

Comment: I've updated my question and I do not get benefit from this link because it is not clear what I should to do

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following 
https://www.nsnam.org/docs/release/3.25/tutorial/singlehtml/index.html#building-ns3

seems to work. (first step 2357 files compiled, so a bit long)

To debug your problem and save all the logging, so to better understand what is missing:

```
python -v build.py |& tee build.log
```

Comment: I have past the result for this command and updated the question body. could you tell me what this result means?

Comment: does `/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload/binascii.dll` exist ? What is the output of `$ cygcheck -c python` ?

Comment: Cygwin Package Information
Package              Version        Status
python               2.7.10-1       OK

Comment: I have added another results using bake

Comment: `/usr/bin/import` seems to miss dependency. Run a full `cygcheck -c` to verify broken installation of any package.

Comment: I have tried this command and got all the displayed packages installed OK

Comment: next resource: `strace -o import.strace /usr/bin/import.exe` . However I wonder why import is used at all by ns3.

Comment: copy past this command to the shell -> I've got : Segmentation fault

Comment: smell same problem of `http://superuser.com/questions/1099936/cygwin-stunnel-doesnt-respond-anymore` : Antivirus interference. Can you disable it ?

Comment: I do not have an antivirus on my PC

Comment: Follow https://cygwin.com/problems.html and post `cygcheck.out` on the cygwin mailing list. Your installation has problem.

Comment: I have updated the question ... I need to work together to identify and solve this problem , because I need this simulator for my research as soon as possible , thank you

Comment: Your problem is NOT a programming question. Read https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda and https://cygwin.com/problems.html and look for support on the cygwin mailing list https://cygwin.com/lists.html

Comment: could you  look to this question:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39307561/how-to-install-and-build-ns-3-using-bake